# When provisioning a Cosmos DB - Gremlin API from PowerShell, is there a way to set the capacity mode to Serverless?

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

When I create a Cosmos DB - Gremlin API from the Azure Portal there is an option to set the capacity mode to serverless:

[image]

However, when I look through the documentation for doing the same through PowerShell, I cannot  find something that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this that some folk at Azure sent over:

```
$resourceGroupName = "my-rg" 
$accountLocation = "Central US"
$accountName = "my-account"
$failoverLocations = @(
     @{ "locationName"="Central US"; "failoverPriority"=0 }
 )
$capabilities= @(@{"name"="EnableServerless"},@{"name"="EnableGremlin"})
$CosmosDBProperties = @{
     "databaseAccountOfferType"="Standard";
     "locations"=$failoverLocations;
     "capabilities"=$capabilities;
 }
New-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" `
     -ApiVersion "2019-12-12" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
     -Location $accountLocation -Name $accountName -PropertyObject $CosmosDBProperties
```

Note that the cmdlet is New-AzResource not New-AzCosmosDBAccount.

Comment: Under capabilities, there is the option to "EnableServerless"...
This is then added to properties of the Cosmos DB

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-6.4.0)'s [`New-AzCosmosDBAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/new-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-6.4.0) command does not yet support setting the capacity mode for an Azure Cosmos DB account (as of Azure PowerShell version 6.4.0).

These are all of the arguments that the command currently supports, none of which are suitable:

```
New-AzCosmosDBAccount
   [-EnableAutomaticFailover]
   [-EnableMultipleWriteLocations]
   [-EnableVirtualNetwork]
   [-FromPointInTimeBackup]
   [-ApiKind <String>]
   [-DisableKeyBasedMetadataWriteAccess]
   [-EnableFreeTier <Boolean>]
   [-Location <String[]>]
   [-LocationObject <PSLocation[]>]
   -ResourceGroupName <String>
   -Name <String>
   [-DefaultConsistencyLevel <String>]
   [-IpRule <String[]>]
   [-MaxStalenessIntervalInSeconds <Int32>]
   [-MaxStalenessPrefix <Int32>]
   [-Tag <Hashtable>]
   [-VirtualNetworkRule <String[]>]
   [-VirtualNetworkRuleObject <PSVirtualNetworkRule[]>]
   [-PublicNetworkAccess <String>]
   [-KeyVaultKeyUri <String>]
   [-EnableAnalyticalStorage <Boolean>]
   [-AsJob]
   [-NetworkAclBypass <String>]
   [-NetworkAclBypassResourceId <String[]>]
   [-ServerVersion <String>]
   [-BackupIntervalInMinutes <Int32>]
   [-BackupRetentionIntervalInHours <Int32>]
   [-BackupPolicyType <String>]
   [-AnalyticalStorageSchemaType <String>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: `Serverless` setting is at the account level and not at the database level. Having said that, I believe it is still not supported in Azure PowerShell.

Comment: @GauravMantri Do you have a reference for that please?

Comment: You would use [New-AzCosmosDBAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/new-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-6.4.0) to provision new account. I was not able to find a parameter for enabling serverless mode there.

Comment: You're correct, "Serverless is a new Azure Cosmos account type" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless, I'll update the answer now

Comment: It's not a new account type per se but a capability for an account.

Comment: Yes, that's an article from months ago but it's at the account level - thanks :)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer by adding the current PowerShell version. I hope you don't mind :).

Comment: @GauravMantri Beat me to it ;)

Comment: I found a solution and just wanted to share it with you guys in case you were still curious. Thanks for the help provided!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who hit this problem and got lost in pages of MS outdated documentation, As per @Diego wrote in a comment. Move to Azure CLI and use the command:

```
az cosmosdb create --name $databaseName --resource-group $resourcegroup --capabilities EnableServerless --locations regionName=$regionName failoverPriority=0
```

As of March 2022, this function isn't available in Azure PowerShell only CLI.